# Elm: How to fetch data on page load with Navigation.newUrl?

Tags: elm

I have an Elm application with multiple pages/routes. I have a "/dashboard" route that needs data on page load.

I had to modify the `init` function for when the user does a hard browser reload, and I had to modify the `update` function's `onLocationChange` clause for when `Navigation.newUrl` is called.

My question is: is this the right way to do this? I hate having to modify two functions when it feels like there should be one place that handles this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could let `update` function handle all the `Cmd` creation.

```
init : Navigation.Location -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init location =
    update
        (LocationChange location)
        initialModel
```